# ¿Retorno dos valores tipo String pero como hago para acceder a los datos de una tabla en mysql?

Tags: java-8

Buenas tardes estoy validando un usuario si existe pero necesito que muestre su rol y su cédula gracias. (MVC).

```
public String[] validaUser(String user, String pass) {

        String sql = "SELECT \n"
                + "u.user,\n"
                + "u.password,\n"
                + "r.rol,\n"
                + "p.cedula,\n"
                + "p.nom_nom,\n"
                + "p.nom_ape\n"
                + "from users as u \n"
                + "INNER JOIN roles as r\n"
                + " ON r.id = u.id_rol\n"
                + "INNER JOIN personal as p\n"
                + " ON p.id = u.id_personal\n"
                + "WHERE u.user = ? AND u.password = ?";

        try {

            cn = con.getConection();
            ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, user);
            ps.setString(2, pass);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (!rs.next()) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario y/o Contraseña invalida.");
                return null;
            } else {
                String[] cedulaRol = {rs.getString("rol"), rs.getString("cedula")};
                return cedulaRol;
                /*return rs.getString("rol");*/
            }

        } catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al traer los datos de los usuario modelo:" + e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Y aquí valida si es docente o administrador pero necesito que muestre: ***"Bienvenido: "+`rol+cedula`***, no se si estaré cometiendo algún error en la base de datos pero la he revisado y consulta bien.

```
private void 

txtIngresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

        mUsuarios datos = new mUsuarios();

        String[] rol = {"rol", "cedula"};

        rol = datos.validaUser(txtLogin.getText(), txtPassword.getText());
        /*rol = datos.validaUser(txtLogin.getText(), txtPassword.getText());
        user = datos.validaUser(txtLogin.getText(), txtPassword.getText());*/

        if (rol.equals("ADMINISTRADOR")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido: " + rol);
            vAdmin form = new vAdmin();
            form.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        } else if (rol.equals("DOCENTE")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido: " + rol);
            vDocente form = new vDocente();
            form.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existen datos");
            txtLogin.setText("");
            txtPassword.setText("");
            txtLogin.requestFocus();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Estás recibiendo el password como texto? txtPassword es un campo de texto o de contraseña? Dependiendo de eso, es posible que debas obtener su valor de otra forma y compararlo de otra forma con lo que está en BD? La contraseña se guarda cifrada de alguna forma?

Comment: ¿Y el problema cuál es? ¿Por qué no imprimes lo que estás recibiendo en `rol` para ver su contenido y estructura?

Comment: Alfabravo en la validacion si entra normalmente hacia el otro frama, pero necesito que me imprima la cedula del docente o administrador, pero eso esta en la consulta trato de retornar un array perro me arroja un error en la validacion

Comment: @A.Cedano el problema es que como se esta declarando como un array a lo que valido me da un error de que no existen datos, en cambio si lo coloco como un string normal valida bien pero no me retorna la cedula, solo el rol

Comment: Me interesa ver lo que esto retorna: `datos.validaUser(txtLogin.getText(), txtPassword.getText());` para poder decirte cómo obtener la información. ¿Podíras mostrarlo por favor?

Comment: @A.Cedano eso se envia como parametros al modelo donde se ejecuta la consulta y retorna los valores

Comment: Pero qué es lo que retorna, muéstralo en la pregunta para poder ayudarte, pues  el código usa `rol` para hacer las comparaciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano, public String validaUser(String user, String pass) si lo declaro asi si me valida es decir no como array y retornaria return rs.getString("rol"); para eso utilizaria esto rol = datos.validaUser(txtLogin.getText(), txtPassword.getText()); pero entonces el solo me devolveria el rol mas no la cedula y necesito los dos. ¿No se si me doy a entender?

Comment: Te entiendo, pero quiero que muestres cómo vienen los datos. Si vienen en un array con dos valores quizá uno esté en `rol[0]` y el otro en `rol[1]`, pero al no ver el contenido del objeto no sé como está viniendo, es por eso que te digo que lo saques por pantalla para analizarlo. No sé si me entiendes.

Comment: Si ya le estoy entendiendo.  String[] cedulaRol = {rs.getString("rol"), rs.getString("cedula")};
                return cedulaRol; aqui es donde clecaro el array y que es lo que me va a traer tal vez sea ahi el error

Comment: Si el dato viene en un array con una sola fila, en el método `txtIngresarActionPerformed` haz los siguientes cambios: 1. borra esto: `String[] rol = {"rol", "cedula"};` 2. pon esto así: `String[] rol = datos.validaUser(txtLogin.getText(), txtPassword.getText());` 3. ahora cambia los `if` a algo así:   `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido: Su rol es: " + rol[0] + " su cédula  es: "+ rol[1]);`

Comment: @A.Cedano si me sirvió y ademas de eso agrega if (rol[0].equals("ADMINISTRADOR")), muchimas gracias de verdad me salvo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tú devuelves un array con dos valores del tipo `String`:

```
String[] cedulaRol = {rs.getString("rol"), rs.getString("cedula")};
return cedulaRol;
```

Lo cual significa que los datos viajarán en un índice `0`, el rol y `1` la cedula (los índices de arrays empiezan por `0`.

Entonces, para leer esos datos tienes que buscarlos por sus índices.

Corregiremos algunas cosas en el código que recibe los datos:

```
txtIngresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

        mUsuarios datos = new mUsuarios();

        //String[] rol = {"rol", "cedula"}; ESTO NO SIRVE DE NADA, BORRARLO

        //Declaramos mData como array de String que es lo que esperamos...
        String[] mData = datos.validaUser(txtLogin.getText(), txtPassword.getText());
        //Declaramos variable, cuestión de gustos... es más claro así
        String rol = mData[0];
        //Hacemos esto una sola vez
        String msg= "Bienvenido: " + rol + " su código es: " + mData[1];

        if (rol.equals("ADMINISTRADOR")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
            vAdmin form = new vAdmin();
            form.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        } else if (rol.equals("DOCENTE")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
            vDocente form = new vDocente();
            form.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existen datos");
            txtLogin.setText("");
            txtPassword.setText("");
            txtLogin.requestFocus();
        }

    }
```